# How do I show an html file in the web view in the latest Swift release Swift 5 Xcode 10.2

Tags: html, swift, xcode, wkwebview, swift5

How can I show my html file in `webview`. This is my code

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        if let urlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "form", ofType: "html", inDirectory: nil) {
            webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: urlPath)))            
        }
    }
}
```

> Could not instantiate class named WKWebView because no class named WKWebView was found; the class needs to be defined in source code or linked in from a library (ensure the class is part of the correct target)'

I want to be able to show the `webview`.

Comment: what the current problem ?

Comment: i keep receiving this message even on code that was working last week and i didn't change anything Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: Which line? What's the error message in console?

Comment: Make sure that the interface builder outlet is still connected to the webView IBOutlet

Comment: So it's in the InterfaceBuilder? Check if there is something (un)checked, likes Modules, etc.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I had to use WebKit framework

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug. One workaround is to:

- select project general properties and under Linked Frameworks and Libraries
- add WebKit.framework